# Material 2.0.0-beta.3 md-slider not dragging

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Hopefully, this is a stupid question.

I just added a md-slider to a project I am building for my employer. (thus I have no code to show sorry)

I Imported MdSliderModule into the module I'm working in. Added the  tag in my template where I wanted it. It showed up and looks great but won't drag. I can click on it to change its value but I can't drag it.

Am I missing something? Does Angular have a Dragging module this component uses that I need to import? Has anyone else seen this?

We are using:

- Angular ^4.0.2
- Material 2.0.0-beta.3

Any help or suggestions of things for me to try will be helpful. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Did you add `hammerjs`?

Comment: @Edric I did not thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem until I discovered that I hadn't installed hammer.js.

```
npm install --save hammerjs
```

then add hammerjs as a dependency in the `scripts` array of your `angular-cli.json` file:

```
 "scripts": [
    //possibly other scripts here...
    "../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
  ],
 ...
```

Hopefully this will resolve the issue - recompile everything to be sure that changes take effect

Comment: Yep! Thank you very much, I was coming on here to answer my own question. I had not needed hammer until this component.

Comment: What should be done if I am not using angular-cli ? KJR @MrfksIV

Comment: I guess you could try to include it in your index.html <head> inside a <script src="....."> tag.

Answer (score 7):

Accepted answer alone didn't work for me.  Finally found [a comment](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4278#issuecomment-317832711) in the issues on github that solved it.  After ensuring hammerjs was installed per [Step 5 Gesture Support](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-5-gesture-support) added this to root.module.ts for the win:

```
import { BrowserModule, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { GestureConfig } from '@angular/material';

providers: [
    { provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: GestureConfig },
]
```

Comment: I did this in addition to the accepted solution, and it worked. Thanks Lee!